# Assign values to new column if condition is met in at least one of the selected columns

Tags: r, if-statement

Here's the problem:
I have an empty column "x", which should take value 1 if number "3210" appears in any of the columns from 11th to 32nd, otherwise x=0.

Due to the large number of columns, I cannot use "ifelse" to check if 3210 appears column by column. is there a simpler way?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably something like `df$mycol <- pmin(rowSums(df[, 11:32] == 3210), 1)`, but without a working example, can't perform any checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply` to run `%in%` on the rows, which because the named parameter is `x` will get passed to the `table` parameter of `%in%`. perhaps:

```
 dat$x <- as.numeric( apply( dat[ , 11:32], 1, `%in%`, x="3210"))
 #now a tested solution on the example offered by @JeremyVolsey
```

Comment: You can wrap the `apply` function with `as.numeric` to turn the boolean output into 0s (FALSE) and 1s (TRUE). `dat$x <- as.numeric(apply(dat,1,'%in%',x="3210"))`

Answer (score 1):

Data for example

```
nos <- c(3210, 1280, 4460, 7840)
set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(nos, 20, replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(nos, 20, replace = TRUE), v3  = sample(nos, 20, replace = TRUE))
```

I've used columns 1:3, to demonstrate the answer

```
my_df$x <- ifelse(rowSums(my_df[,1:3] == 3210) >= 1, 1, 0)

     v1   v2  v3 x
1  1280 7840 3210 1
2  7840 4460 1280 0
3  1280 4460 1280 0
4  7840 7840 1280 0
5  7840 4460 3210 1
6  3210 4460 3210 1
7  4460 4460 3210 1
8  7840 4460 1280 0
9  4460 1280 1280 0
10 1280 3210 7840 1
11 7840 7840 3210 1
12 1280 7840 1280 0
13 4460 4460 7840 0
14 4460 7840 3210 1
15 3210 3210 4460 1
16 7840 1280 3210 1
17 3210 7840 3210 1
18 3210 3210 7840 1
19 1280 1280 7840 0
20 7840 3210 1280 1
```

Comment: Upvoted for tested solution, but you really, really, really should stop using `c` and `df` as data-object names. They are also function names and especially in the case of `c` you will get really strange error messages and create code the is difficult to read. I use `dat` or `dfrm` for my generic data.frame names.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, Jeremy!

Comment: Hi @Denis if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.